# How to simplify code, which adds spaces and commas if field value is not empty?

Tags: javascript

```
var searchDetails = "";
searchDetails += $("#last-name").val();
searchDetails += searchDetails != "" ? " "+$("#first-name").val() : $("#first-name").val();
searchDetails += searchDetails != "" ? " "+$("#middle-name").val() : $("#middle-name").val();
if ($("#dob-dd").val() != "" || $("#dob-mm").val() != "" || $("#dob-yyyy").val() != "") {
    searchDetails += searchDetails != "" ? ", " : "";
    searchDetails += "date of birth: ";
    searchDetails += ($("#dob-dd").val() != "" ? $("#dob-dd").val() : "xx") + ".";
    searchDetails += ($("#dob-mm").val() != "" ? $("#dob-mm").val() : "xx") + ".";
    searchDetails += ($("#dob-yyyy").val() != "" ? $("#dob-yyyy").val() : "xx") + ".";
}
if ($("#passport-id").val() != "") {
    searchDetails += searchDetails != "" ? ", " : "";
    searchDetails += "passport " + $("#passport-id").val();
}
```

`searchDetails` should contain values like (depending on what user has input):

```
lastName firstName middleName, date of birth dd.mm.yyyy, passport 123456789
firstName middleName, date of birth dd.xx.yyyy
lastName firstName, date of birth dd.mm.xxxx
date of birth dd.mm.xxxx, passport 123456789
lastName firstName middleName
passport 123456789
```

Comment: Shouldn't the fallback value for `dob-yyyy` be `xxxx`? Your code only uses `xx` for the year, but your examples show `xxxx`

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I'd create a helper function for the `!= ""` check:

```
function isEmptyString(value) {
    if (value == "") {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

It would make the code easier to read.

Then I'd extract out a function for sturctures like `($("#dob-dd").val() != "" ? $("#dob-dd").val() : "xx") + "."`:

```
function wrapDateOfBirth(id) {
    return ($(id).val() != "" ? $(id).val() : "xx") + ".";
}
```

and structures like `searchDetails != "" ? " "+$("#first-name").val() : $("#first-name").val();`:

```
function wrapSearchDetails($value, $id) {
    return $value != "" ? " " + $($id).val() : $($id).val();
}
```

They would remove some duplication.

Furthermore, the `wrapSearchDetails` function could be written like this too:

```
function wrapSearchDetails(value, id) {
    return (isEmptyString(value) ? "" : " ") + $(id).val();
}
```

The `wrapDateOfBirth` function also could be simplified:

```
function wrapDateOfBirth(id) {
    var value = $(id).val();
    return (isEmptyString(value) ? "xx" : value) + ".";
}
```

Finally, a `getDefaultIfEmpty` function also could improve the readability of the `wrapDateOfBirth` function:

```
function getDefaultIfEmpty(value, defaultValue) {
    if (isEmptyString(value)) {
        return defaultValue;
    }
    return value;
}

function wrapDateOfBirth(id) {
    var value = $(id).val();
    return getDefaultIfEmpty(value, "xx") + ".";
}
```

(I have not tested the code, please feel free to edit if you find any typo/etc.)

Comment: Nicely detailed walkthrough. A few comments though: The `isEmptyString` function is equivalent to just writing `!value`, since a zero-length string is false'y. But you might want to check for whitespace-only strings, and/or do strict comparisons (`===`) against `""`, in which case the function is a good place to implement it.

Comment: @Flambino: For the `== ""` comparison you don't have to know that *a zero-length string is false*, so I think it's easier to understand and therefore less error-prone. I agree with the second sentence.

Comment: True, `== ""` is easier to understand. JavaScript's ideas on what is and what isn't false'y can trip anyone up. Something else, though: Your functions might benefit from consistent parity/signatures. Right now, some take both value and ID, and some take only the ID.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is to use arrays. Perhaps more cryptic at first glance, but makes good use of `join()`, and jQuery's utility functions:

```
function composeSearchDetails() {
  var name, dob, passport, searchDetails;

  // Get the name
  name = [
    $("#last-name").val(),
    $("#first-name").val(),
    $("#middle-name").val()
  ];

  // Strip out empty and all-whitespace strings
  name = jQuery.grep(name, function (value) {
    return jQuery.trim(value) !== ""; // false if string is empty or all-whitespace
  });

  // Join if not empty
  name = name.length ? name.join(" ") : false;

  // Get the DoB parts, or their fallback ("xx") values 
  dob = [
    jQuery.trim($("#dob-dd").val()) || "xx",
    jQuery.trim($("#dob-mm").val()) || "xx",
    jQuery.trim($("#dob-yyyy").val()) || "xxxx"
  ];

  // Join
  dob = dob.join(".");

  // Check that there's at least 1 non-X value
  dob = /[^x.]/.test(dob) ? "date of birth " + dob : false;

  // Get the passport
  passport = jQuery.trim($("#passport-id").val());
  passport = passport ? "passport " + passport : false;

  // Put it together
  searchDetails = [name, dob, passport];

  // Get rid of false parts
  searchDetails = jQuery.grep(searchDetails, function (value) { return value; });

  // Join and return
  return searchDetails.join(", ");
}
```

[Here's a live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/m4JZn/)

*Note: `jQuery.grep` can be replaced with the native ECMA5 `.filter` function, if available*

Answer (score 1):

- `!= ""` checks are unnecessary - `.val()` always returns a string, and every string but `""` evaluates to `true`.
- Don't call $(id).val() repeatedly; cache the result the first time.
- Build it up as an array then, at the end, use `.join()`. This avoids all the checks to `searchDetails != "" ? ", " : ""`.
- in javascript, logical operators return the last value, not a boolean cast of the last value. What that means in that instead of calling `str ? str : "xx"`, you can write `str || 'xx'`.

Here's my take on your problem.

```
function getSearchDetails() {
    var searchDetails = [],
        firstName = $('#first-name').val(),
        middleName = $('#middle-name').val(),
        lastName = $('#last-name').val(),
        dobD = $('#dob-dd').val(),
        dobM = $('#dob-mm').val(),
        dobY = $('#dob-yyyy').val(),
        passportID = $('#passport-id').val();

    if (firstName || middleName || lastName) {
        searchDetails.push([
            lastName,
            firstName,
            middleName
        ].join(' ').replace(/(^| )( +|$)/g, ''));
    }
    if (dobD || dobM || dobY) {
        searchDetails.push(
            'date of birth: ' +
            (dobD || 'xx') + '.' +
            (dobM || 'xx') + '.' +
            (dobY || 'xx') + '.';
        );
    }
    if (passportID) {
        searchDetails.push('passport ' + passportID);
    }
    return searchDetails.join(', ');
}
```

Comment: Nice and concise, but it always includes the name part, even if the name fields are blank (and it doesn't ignore all-whitespace input, although neither does the original code). I set up [a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Evmqu/)

Comment: @Flambino thanks, I missed that - answer updated. The whitespace part was intentional though, as LA_ seems satisfied with the code's current functionality.